# Array of list convert to object

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I have an object which looks like this:

```
   const test = {
    {
     'ADF':['test']
    },
    {
     'BDF':['test']
    }
    ,
    {
     'CDF':['test']
    }
    }
```

1) I am extracting the keys like this

```
const key = Object.key(test); // ['ADF', 'BDF', 'CDF']
```

Now I want to create an object like this: {'ADF': ADF, 'BDF': BDF, 'CDF': CDF}

How can I do this?

I tried

```
const objectOfKeys = key.map((item) => {item : item})
```

but I am getting the error unused label for the key item

Solution:

{ [item]: item }

Comment: You realise that your test object is not valid? I guess it should be an array

Comment: Do you want `{ [item]: item }`? It's not clear to me quite what output you're expecting.

Comment: Yes like this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

With ES5 and above, you can just do,

```
const array =  Object.keys(test);;
console.log({...array});
```

Comment: "With ES5 and above". ES5 is not enough. Object spread is stage 4 proposal.

Comment: Here is the key as index. I will need the same name like the value

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `reduce` function:

```
const initialObject = [
  {
    'ADF': ['test']
  },
  {
    'BDF': ['test']
  }
  ,
  {
    'CDF': ['test']
  }
];

const finalObject = initialObject.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [currentKey] = Object.keys(curr)
  acc[currentKey] = currentKey;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(finalObject);
```

Output:

```
{ADF: "ADF", BDF: "BDF", CDF: "CDF"}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-22elrq